# Grails findBy multiple columns Ilike

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a simple Tag class with only two fields, name and value,

```
class Tag {
    String name
    String value
}
```

and I'm trying to render an XML where I want to search for parts of both parameters via findBy...Ilike().

```
def getXml = {
    render Tag.findAllByNameAndValueIlike("%${params.name}%", "%${params.value}%") as XML
}
```

But this doesn't give my any results. If I use only one parameter, it works as I expect:

```
def getXml = {
    render Tag.findAllByNameIlike("%${params.name}%") as XML
}
```

My next question is probably going to be about filtering the results, and adding other "similar" tags to the returns list, so is there a way to solve the above with something like:

```
def getXml = {
    list = Tag.findAllByNameIlike("%${params.name}%")
    list.add(Some other stuff)
    list.sortBy(Some thing, maby name length)
}
```

Comment: Have you try to used the withCriteria method or the criteria to fo your request ?

Answer (score 2):

For your multiple-field `ilike` query you can use [`withCriteria`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withCriteria.html):

```
def result = Tag.withCriteria {
    ilike('name', "%${params.name}%")
    ilike('value', "%${params.value}%")
}
```

This will return a list of `Tag` domains whose name matches the provided name *and* value matches the provided value.

The [Criteria DSL](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) will probably let you do most of the filtering you need, but you can also consider using some of the Groovy [collection examples here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to be a easy and flexible way to go. Sorry, I'm also new to stackoverflow. It seems I have to post my reply as a new answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the restrictions(InList, NotNull, etc) on each field of a dynamic finder. If you do not, it assumes equals. Here is what you were looking for:

`Tag.findAllByNameIlikeAndValueIlike("%${params.name}%", "%${params.value}%")`

Answer (score 1):

Both answer are good. I tried both, but I have to say I like the withcCritia the best. It seems very flexibly.

```
    def result = Tag.withCriteria {
        if(params.name != null)
            ilike('name', "%${params.name}%")
        if(params.value != null)
            ilike('value', "%${params.value}%")
    }
    result.add(new Tag('name': "something"))
    render result as XML
```